# Problem with using components from a custom component library that (eventually) depend on context

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-context, rollup

I have a problem with understanding how my application that consumes components from a custom component library produces this error (coming from `react-dnd`):

```
Invariant Violation: Expected drag drop context
```

Of course I get that it cannot find the context value that is necessary. However, it seems I am not able to provide a proper context value.

Assume my library looks as follow:

```js
// src/DndComponent.tsx
import * as ReactDnd from "react-dnd";

const DndComponent = () => {
  const [, drag] = ReactDnd.useDrag(
    () => ({
      type: "some-type",
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
      }),
    }),
    []
  );

  return <div ref={drag}>Drag me</div>;
};

export default DndComponent;
```

```js
// index.ts
export { default as DndComponent } from "./DndComponent";
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "ui-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/index.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dnd": "14.0.5",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "14.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "17.0.45",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "3.1.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.3",
    "vite": "4.1.4",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "2.4.0"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.umd.cjs"
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { resolve } from "path";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      name: "index",
      fileName: "index",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react", "react-dnd", "react-dnd-html5-backend"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "react",
          "react-dnd": "react-dnd",
          "react-dnd-html5-backend": "react-dnd-html5-backend",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

And my application looks like this:

```js
// App.tsx
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDnd from "react-dnd";
import { HTML5Backend } from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
import { DndComponent } from "ui-lib";

function App() {
  return (
    <ReactDnd.DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
      <DndComponent />
    </ReactDnd.DndProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
// package.json
{
  "name": "app-dir",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "npm run build && vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dnd": "14.0.5",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "14.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "ui-lib": "file:../ui-lib"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "3.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.3",
    "vite": "4.1.4"
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am wrapping `DndComponent` inside `ReactDnd.DndProvider` which should provide the context value.

If I re-export `DndProvider` and `HTML5Backend` from `ui-lib` and consume these instead of directly from `react-dnd` and `react-dnd-html5-backend`, I don't have any issues and everything seems to work as expected:

```js
// index.ts (ui-lib)
export { default as DndComponent } from "./DndComponent";
export { DndProvider } from "react-dnd"; // re-export from 'react-dnd' inside `ui-lib`
export { HTML5Backend } from "react-dnd-html5-backend"; // re-export from 'react-dnd-html5-backend' inside `ui-lib`
```

```js
// App.tsx (app)
import React from "react";
import { DndComponent, DndProvider, HTML5Backend } from "ui-lib"; // consume from `ui-lib`

function App() {
  return (
    <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
      <DndComponent />
    </DndProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I found [How to share context between different component libraries in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993563), [React Context API not working from custom NPM component library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976672) or [How to share context between multiple libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70076361) that seem to have a very similar problem.

But as you can see, I already added `react-dnd` and `react-dnd- html5-backend` as `peerDependencies` and added both to the Rollup config's `external` property as well.